# Yocto - "/bin/sh: 1: bc: not found"

Tags: linux, makefile, driver, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to add a driver from OpenEmbedded Layer Index (https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/72354/) to my Yocto project.
I'm getting an error during compiling the driver:
`/bin/sh: 1: bc: not found`
I've added to the recipe `DEPENDS += "bc bc-native"` and `bc` to `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` but it didn't solve my problem.
Do you have any idea what else I can do?

Comment: [`bc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc) is the executable that the shell can't find. Do you have it installed?

Comment: It is added to `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` variable. I can find the binary file in `/build/tmp/work/<machine>/<image>/rootfs/usr/bin`.

Comment: Then your path needs to include `/build/tmp/work/<machine>/<image>/rootfs/usr/bin`, otherwise `/bin/sh` won't find it.

Comment: I've just added `EXTRA_OEMAKE += "-I${S}/usr/bin' "` to the recipe and it works. Thanks.